# Using variable from code behind in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables

I'm having a bit of difficulty setting a variable from the code behind and utilising it in the ASP.NET page (setting it as the value inside a textbox). My webpage simply errors and says it does not exist in the current context. The variable is declared and set all in the Page_Load method.

Here is the relevant ASP.NET code. I assume you will not need to see the code behind, as I have tested outputting the variable via the codebehind (using Response.Write) and that works fine.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Initial Path" 
                SortExpression="Initial_Path">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# initialPath %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# initialPath %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# initialPath %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks :)

EDIT: Ok sure, here's the relevant parts of the code behind

```
       string schedID = sched.SchedulerInstanceId;
        JobDetail jobDetail2 = sched.GetJobDetail(Request.QueryString["JOB_NAME"], "sched1");
        JobDataMap dataMap2 = jobDetail2.JobDataMap;
        initialPath = dataMap2.GetString("initialPath");
        Response.Write(initialPath);
```

The response.write is for debugging - it outputs the variable correctly so the variable is actually set

EDIT 2: Here is the code behind

```
public partial class EditJobDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    public string initialPath { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Scheduler stuff for Quartz.NET, removed because of length

        string schedID = sched.SchedulerInstanceId;
        JobDetail jobDetail2 = sched.GetJobDetail(Request.QueryString["JOB_NAME"], "sched1");
        JobDataMap dataMap2 = jobDetail2.JobDataMap;
        initialPath = dataMap2.GetString("initialPath");
    }
```

What's not working is just the <%= initialpath %> in the ASP form. It simply just doesn't show anything, like the variable is assigned nothing

Comment: Your code-behind is at *least* as important to this problem.  Can you show us that too?

Comment: I think we need more information as Kirk said. The Edit still doesn't tell us if "initialPath" is public, or if its accessed via a property...

Comment: Sorry, I've now made the variable public as CrazyDart demonstrated below, so the variable declartion is like this:

Comment: public string initialPath { get; set; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I don't see here is where the call to `DataBind()` is made. If it's made before is set then `<%#initialPath%>` will write its starting value (null, which gets written as an empty string in such a case). If it's not made at all, then `<%#initialPath%>` will never write anything. You need to make sure `DataBind()` is called at an appropriate time, such as at the end of `Page_Load`

Comment: Ah, I put DataBind at the end and it now works fine. Thanks, and thanks also to everyone who helped :)

Answer (score 12):

In the codebehind you need to create it as a public property.  Then you can use it all you want in the aspx page.

in code behind:

```
public string yourvar { get; set; }
```

in aspx:

```
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" 
            Text='<%= yourvar %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Cheers buddy, but for some reason the field it's supposed to be in the ASP.NET form is blank

Comment: In your Page_Load you do need to set the content of your var, can you post sample code of whats not working?  Please include the property, the pageload and the aspx.

Comment: Added the relevant parts :) the actual variable is assigning as I can output it from the code behind using Response.Write, but I can't get it to transfer over using <%= initialPath %>

Comment: ok, so I think I am starting to get the situation... the TemplateField needs to have a data source.  Its made to iterate over a collection of something, not just display a string.

Comment: I'm using the template fields as part of a details view - most of the things I need to display in the details view are simply fields from the table so that is automatically done. For some of the fields, including this, it's installed inside a 'binary image' as I'm using Quartz.NET, and to get the information out I need to do some work in the codebehind, if that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

`<%# initialPath %>` is a databinding expression meaning that ASP.NET will look for a `initialPath` property on the collection you are binding to. Obviously such property doesn't exist as this is a local variable.